# Angular validate standard proper email in Ionic 3 App

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, ionic-framework, email-validation

This question maybe exist multiple times but I tried googling for it and try it out but it won't work in my case.

I have a [FormBuilder](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder) with an **email** input in my **Ionic 3 App**

This is my **Validators** in my **formBuilder** for email.

```
 email: [
        "",
        Validators.compose([
          Validators.pattern(`/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/`),
          Validators.required
        ])
      ],
```

I found this regEx right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript).

In my **html code**

```
    <ion-input formControlName="email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail Address *"></ion-input>
  <validation-messages *ngIf="form.controls['email'].errors.pattern" [message]="'This is not a valid E-mail address'"></validation-messages> // Component validator message
```

When I still able to type a correct email address it sais that it is incorrect for example.

> testing@gmail.com // Not a valid email

I had also tried this **regEx** pattern below:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$
```

This one works but if I tried to input:

```
testing@gmail // Valid email which it should be not. Need to use .com .org or any that starts with a dot after the @domain
```

I knew this is just a simple question.

But can't find the proper solution.

Appreciate if someone could help
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you have set `type="email"` you do not need any patterns. Webview will handle the validation for you.

Comment: @KoshVery but I would like to show the message of the validation. How can I do that

Comment: There is a great article on MDN on [Form data validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation). Please have read it all.

Comment: Angular has validator for email - ``Validators.email`` maybe this is a way?

Comment: @Buczkowski I didn't try that out. But I already find the solution